# Preventing Excel Chart AutoFill

Tags: vba, excel, charts

I need to create a `Chart` in Excel using VBA.

Just using a simple script as below:

```
Dim Chart1 As Chart
Set Chart1 = Charts.Add
```

This inserts the `Chart` as expected. However, depending on my cursor position the `Chart` will AutoFill / Auto Populate with the relevant surrounding data.

See two examples below:

[image]

The obvious and simple way to avoid this is to select the Cursor via `VBA` to a definite blank cell location.

I can also have a `Loop` to run through all the `SeriesCollection` in the `Chart` and delete them.

I there something like a `Chart1.ClearContent`? or what else could I do?

Comment: You can also use SetSourceData to change to whatever data you actually want.

Comment: @Rory that is a very easy step which i like. I just used it to ensure that the chart has no data set with  `Chart1.SetSourceData (DataWorkSheet.Cells(1, 1))` which then cleared the data. Could you post as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use the chart's `SetSourceData` method to change to whatever data you actually want, or simply point it at a blank cell:

```
Chart1.SetSourceData Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
```

for example.

Answer (score 0):

> > The obvious and simple way to avoid this is to select the Cursor via VBA to a definite blank cell location.

Just do that, then. That's not too hard and faster than cleaning out gunk from a chart. One of the few events where .Select is useful.